# Display list metadata on list item hover/click on list item

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, custom-list, list-view-web-part

I know what I want to do, but do not know if I am approaching it correctly.  I have a custom list with a number of metadata columns. When I or user selects an item from a list I would like for the view items to display to the right of the list.

My idea is web part connection, but I am not sure if I am headed in the right direction. Can someone tell me if this the best approach to show view item?

Comment: Are you referring to the Preview Pane list style?

Comment: @EricAlexander Thank you for your comment. Yes in a way.  On each line item you can select the ellipses that allows you to select View Item.  I would like for that information to appear automatically to the right of the list (in a separate web part) if the item on the list is selected.

Comment: achievable, but requires some (serious) JavaScripting. Challenge with using CSR (Client Side Rendering) is that the View will not include all item columns, so you have to do an extra Query, get all Item fields, and display those in another DIV (second webpart)

Comment: @DannyEngelman Thanks, Danny for the warning!  I will try to think of another way to achieve this task.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

You can preview list item metadata on hover of list item.

Like:
[image]

Reference Links are

[Link1](http://spjsblog.com/2013/12/03/list-view-preview-item-on-hover/)  [Link2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/sharepoint-2013-preview-the-list-item/)  [Link3](http://spjsblog.com/2012/02/12/list-view-preview-item-on-hover-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Somebody tested in SharePoint Online in 2018? Cannot get it working..

Comment: upd.: think they changed calculated columns after 'column formatting' feature. But I used CSR instead, looks like it works.